# Can pathauto aliases be applied to taxonomy menu blocks?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have got the taxonomy alias patterns working but for some reason my taxonomy menu block is not using them.

Is there something I need to do/enable/kill/worship to get a taxonomy menu block to respect the taxonomy aliases generated by path auto?

Comment: Do you mean the links within the taxonomy menu are not using their aliases? (as a block cannot have an path alias)

Comment: Yeah the links. They are using aliases but not the taxonomy ones if you check via the taxonomy admin. It's a bit weird.